# VBA in Access: Sheet.Delete Method not working in a For Next Loop

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm a Life Scientist attempting to code for the first time and trying to build an Access Database for my measurement data. So I'm very inexperienced.

I have embedded an Excel Object in an Access Form that I want to use for calculations. I cannot use the object without deleting its old data first, which I am using a For... Next Loop (code see below). It works *sometimes*, usually the first try, sometimes the first three tries. I need it to work consistently.

I've tried isolating the problem, but it comes down to the wbAnalysis.Sheets.(iSheetCounter).Delete line just.. not doing anything? None of the fixes I have found (activating the workbook, creating an Excel Object and disabling Errors there instead of via Excel.Application) seem to do anything.

The code does not throw an error of any kind, it runs just fine, it just does not delete the sheets.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim wbAnalysis As Excel.Workbook
    Dim iSheetCounter As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Object

    Set wbAnalysis = Me!OLEExcel.Object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        For iSheetCounter = 1 To wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count
            If wbAnalysis.Sheets.Count > 1 Then
                appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
                wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter).Activate
                wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter).UsedRange.Delete
                wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter).Delete
                appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next iSheetCounter

End Sub
```

I've edited the code to look like this after the comments. It unfortunately, still only works about half the time, with the other half throwing a windows error sound without any messagebox.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()

    Dim wbAnalysis As Excel.Workbook
    Dim iSheetCounter As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Object

    Set wbAnalysis = Me!OLEExcel.Object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        For iSheetCounter = 1 To wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count
            If wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
                'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
                wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter).Delete
                'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next iSheetCounter

End Sub
```

It was an Excel instance problem. The 'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False` line does not turn off DisplayAlerts for the instance of Excel in which the OLE Object is open. The solution looks as follows:

```
 Dim wbAnalysis As Excel.Workbook
    Dim iSheetCounter As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim nSheets As Long


    Set wbAnalysis = Me!OLEExcel.Object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    nSheets = wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count

        For iSheetCounter = nSheets To 2 Step -1
            If wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
                wbAnalysis.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wbAnalysis.Worksheets(iSheetCounter).Delete
                wbAnalysis.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next iSheetCounter
```

Comment: Note that `Worksheets.Count` and `Sheets.Count` are not synonyms and can result in different numbers. `Worksheets` contains only worksheets but `Sheets` contains all kind of sheets like worksheets, chart sheets and so on. So you need to be consistent here. Don't mix them. • Also the 2 lines right before `wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter).Delete` are useless if you delete the sheet anyway. Remove them. Comment out `appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False` and see if you get any messages.

Comment: I figured that maybe the sheet did not delete when the sheet contained data, that is why I added the lines. I removed them. When commenting out the `appExcel.DisplayAlert` lines, the code works for the first three iterations, and then I can hear the microsoft error sound, but not get any message box to help me.

Comment: what is the value of `wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count` when it raises an error? could be you are deleting the last worksheet? A Workbook must contain 1 worksheet at least.

Comment: The value of `wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count` is generally less than I started with. E.g. right now, the value started with 40, I got it down to 37, and then the error was thrown/the code did not delete another worksheet. I restarted the form and started with 37, endet at 31, etc.

Comment: It shouldn't delete the last worksheet because of the if-clause.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is due to this line `wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter).Delete` Initially it deletes the sheets just fine, but each time a sheet is deleted, the length of  `Worksheets` object decreases. So after some point, it won't get a corresponding sheet when the total number of available sheets is less than the `iSheetCounter`. Try the below code. This will continue to delete the first available sheet until there is only one sheet left.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()

    Dim wbAnalysis As Excel.Workbook
    Dim iSheetCounter As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Object

    Set wbAnalysis = Me!OLEExcel.Object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        For iSheetCounter = 1 To wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count
            If wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
                'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
                wbAnalysis.Worksheets(1).Delete
                'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next iSheetCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly! I was going to post this right now, It's not a code problem, it's more a math problem. Upvoted!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, If I try your code, the `wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count` value does not decrease at all (stays at 29). I've tried using `wbAnalysis.Worksheets(2).Delete` as well, which does not do anything either. I'm slowly considering giving up :D

Answer (score 2):

When deleting objects from a collection by index number in a loop, it's always best to do so from the last to the first one.

Like this:

```
' to avoid problems if .Count changes during the loop, save it in a variable
nSheets = wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count
' countdown loop from last to second sheet
For iSheetCounter = nSheets To 2 Step -1
    wbAnalysis.Worksheets(iSheetCounter ).Delete
Next iSheetCounter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still can't get it to run. The wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count Property stays at 29 even after the loop:  `nSheets = wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count
    

        For iSheetCounter = nSheets To 2 Step -1
            'If wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
                'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
                wbAnalysis.Worksheets(iSheetCounter).Delete
                'appExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
            'End If
        Next iSheetCounter
        
    nSheets = wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count`

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle, it is never a good idea to add or delete items in a collection while you're iterating over the collection. Much better to use code that looks like this.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click()

    Dim wbAnalysis As Excel.Workbook
    Dim iSheetCounter As Integer
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim toDelete As New Collection

    Set wbAnalysis = Me!OLEExcel.Object
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' decide which items to delete
    For iSheetCounter = 1 To wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count
        If wbAnalysis.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            toDelete.Add wbAnalysis.Sheets(iSheetCounter)
        End If
    Next iSheetCounter
    
    ' delete items
    for each ws in toDelete
        ws.delete
    next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: That *"is never a good idea to add or delete items in a collection while you're iterating over the collection"* is only half true. It is a performant and safe solution as long as you ensure that deleting items does not affect the index of your yet **unprocessed** items. Means you loop from the last to the first item and you are safe. • Because what you did is not the best idea neither. Creating another collection out of that collection and looping again takes at least up to double the time for looping.